# Interrupting a method but continue executing the remainer of the code

Tags: c++, signals

I want to run a section of my code but with the option to interrupt it (ctrl-c) before it is completely done and resume executing the rest of my code.  (I am working on a Linux platform.)

My guess is to create fork, call the method, and then use signal handling. What steps are  needed for the signal handling?

```
void Manager::Run()
{
    pid_t pID = fork();

    if( pID<0 )
        exit(1);//give up here
    else if( pID==0 ) {            
        BuildList(); //I'd like the option to ctrl-c this only
        //some code here catch user signal interrupt?
    }
    else {;}

    waitpid(pID,NULL,0);//pause until BuildList() is done or interrupted


    PrintList();
}
```

It looks like I would want to use a line like signal(SIGINT,sigint) somewhere in if/else part.  And I would need to define a function like this:

```
sigint(int param){ signal(param, SIG_DFL);};
```

Except I only want to kill the child process.

Is this the right idea to solve my problem? If so, what signal handling is needed to make this work?

**UPDATE:**
To more completely address my question I explored the suggested non-forking methods. It seems reasonable that I should be able to do this without the fork.  Unfortunately, I am now stuck on compile errors from a few of my attempts. I have included the updated code and new errors.

in Manager.hh

```
    static void sighandler(int signum)
    {
        PrintList();
        exit(1);
    };
```

Manager.cc contains

```
void Manager::Run()
{
    signal(SIGINT,sighandler);//sets up sighandler()
    BuildList(); //add elements to a list
    signal(SIGINT,SIG_DFL);   //restore default 
    PrintList();  
}
```

If the sighandler function is not static I get this:
`error: argument of type 'void (Manager::)(int)' does not match 'void (*)(int)'`
on the call `signal(SIGINT,sighandler)` in Manager::Run() to set up the handler.

If I call PrintList() in a static sighandler function I get this:
`error: cannot call member function 'void Manager::PrintList()' without object`
on the `PrintList();` call in sighandler().

Lastly I note that making PrintList() a static function (with a static sighandler), I get these errors on the List and the iterator to step through the list.
`error: invalid use of member 'Manager::theList' in static member function`
`error: invalid use of member 'Manager::it' in static member function`

Any clever ways around these errors?

Comment: I think you should pose your signal problem in a separate question.  It might be more likely to be answered as well if you accept an answer to your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the function you wish to interrupt, this might be implemented without forking.

If the function doing its processing in a loop, the signal handler can set a boolean indicating you want processing to stop. The loop can just check this boolean and the function can exit safely and in a consistent sate once it's set by the signal handler.

Comment: Good point -- my answer assumes he wanted multiple processes (or threads) for other reasons, but if it's only for interruptibility then a signal handler and global boolean is far simpler.

Comment: Thanks, I had wrongly convinced myself into thinking I needed a fork.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are explicitly sharing memory (say with `mmap`) then your `fork` child is not going to produce results you can see.  Assuming you fixed that, you could `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)` to ignore ctrl-C in the parent (before `fork`) and then reset it back to default in the child with `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL)`.

If you use threads instead (to simpilfy the memory sharing) then the answer changes:  `SIGINT` is an *asynchronous* signal, meaning it does not arise from the execution of an instruction in a particular thread (in contrast, `SIGSEGV` is a synchronous signal).  In a threaded application there is one shared signal handler for all threads.  For asynchronous signals it could be delivered to any of your threads.  That handler would need to set some variable visible to the inner loop of `BuildList()` so it could terminate gracefully.

A note on ignoring `SIGINT`:  It *will* annoy you at some point when you just want to kill your whole application and now ctrl-C doesn't do anything.  Inevitably I find myself cursing such applications as I find other ways to kill them (ctrl-\ to send `SIGQUIT`, or ctrl-Z + `kill`).

Comment: "That handler would need to set some variable visible to the inner loop of BuildList() so it could terminate gracefully". If you are using threads in this way, can you use `pthread_cancel` from the signal handler, and `pthread_testcancel` in the inner loop, to avoid rolling your own mechanism? I'm concerned `pthread_cancel` isn't signal-safe, though, and I suppose it's not a very *big* mechanism.

Comment: Whatever you do you don't want to leak resources in `BuildList()`, which sounds like a function that allocates memory.  Even if you set cancelability type to `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED` there are still several cancellation points besides an explicit `pthread_testcancel`.  There may be ways around this -- I haven't used `pthread_cancel` much outside of toy applications.

Comment: fair enough, although `malloc` doesn't contain a cancellation point so really it depends how this list is going to get built. Generally those other cancellation points are things that block a long time, so you do *want* them there for cancel-on-timeout, checking a flag may be inadequate if you're blocking when it's set. I think thread cancellation may be one of those things that aren't worth using until you learn them properly including the pitfalls, then they make sense. I do recall you can accidentally introduce cancellation points to uncancellable code by switching on your logging.